# IIS AppPool running as x64 (not Managed) - Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

My ASP.NET web application is running in IIS. Sometimes I am unable to debug it and the JIT debugging commands (`Debugger.Launch()` and `Debugger.Break()`) do not work.

When this happens, I can use Debug / "Attach to Process" in VS 2015 and the w3wp.exe process is listed with a type `x64` rather than the usual `Managed (v4.0.30319), x64`.

How is this possible, and how do I fix it?

I am building in Debug mode, and the web.config has

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

All the settings I can find in the project and IIS are the same as dozens of other projects that all work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that I had the **AppPool** set with:

```
Start Mode     AlwaysRunning
```

[image]

but the **website** was:

```
Preload Enabled     False
```

[image]

I was, therefore, seeing an effectively empty App Pool, so it was listed as `x64` and not Managed.

Once I set the website to `Preload Enabled`, it was fine again.

Comment: Saved a bunch of my time. Thanks!